# SQLite security options do I need to encrypt the db?

Tags: database, windows, macos, sqlite

I've wrote an application for Mac OSX and Windows platforms initially and will hopefully get ported to iOS and Android later on in the year. The application uses a sqlite database which stores data such as customers, invoices etc.

On installation of my app, the sqlite database goes into a common folder(documents usually) which has read and write privileges by the app. Once finalised the database will be protected using a hashed+salted password.

The app is designed to be user specific, not a multi user app. My question is do I need to worry about encrypting that database? Do other vendors of CRMs on MAC/Windows encrypt sqlite databases that are local? I've looked at the SEE and SQLCipher from a thread I found 2013,but they all seem very expensive for a noob any other reliable alternatives out there three years on?

I'm mainly concerned about someone having access to the computer who is not the owner and copying over the database onto a flashdrive or something and reading it. Not sure if that will happen but I'm just looking at all bases. Not too bothered about the owner doing it as they own the data but you can't differentiate between them. Just curious as to what other app developers have done and whether there is some legislation/best practices I need to follow to release the app on the app store?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can use SQLCipher without paying as it is an open source project:
[SQLiteCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/open-source/)

You only have to pay for the Commercial/Enterprise edition.